# Why don't airliners use crescent wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airliner, wing

The crescent wing design seen on the Victor bomber seems to have a great number of advantages...

- the critical mach remains more constant along the span, so the formation of shock waves is more even and has less pitch trim changes at high speed
- higher inboard sweep at the point where the wing is the thickest increases the overall critical mach and thereby improves transonic performance
- the curvature (somewhat?) reduces spanwise flow, thereby lowering tip-stall effects at low speed
- when such a stall does occur, it happens at a point closer to the MAC, so the magnitude of the pitch-up is lower
- because of the geometry of the approach, some designs will have a natural flare built-in - this was a major positive benefit on the Victor, although not a design goal

So... with all of these advantages, why doesn't everyone use them? Is there some disadvantage that is not being mentioned?

Comment: The requested *disadvantages* are covered in the linked post, which would be a candidate for being a duplicate [per meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844): *Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers.** This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.*